# Adjoin two generic Eithers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a way to join two `Either a b` and `Either c d` together, having `Either a (Either b (Either c d))` as the end result. But it also should be able to recursively "flat" two eithers, in case if `b ~ Either` or/and `d ~ Either`.

I've tried to define type class with fundep:

```hs
class Adjoin a b c | a b -> c where
  adjoin :: a -> b -> c
```

But couldn't come up with any meaningful instances for the class. I feel it could be achieved through the type families, but I'm not proficient enough for it.

Essentially, I'm trying to reproduce shapeless [Coproduct](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/coproduct.scala) from Scala

Comment: What do you mean by "flat"?

Comment: Saying, I have `Either a b` and `Either c d` where `b ~ Either e f` and `d ~ Either g h`, in the end it should be `Either a (Either e (Either f (Either c (Either g h))))` instead of `Either (Either a (Either e f)) (Either c (Either g h))`

Comment: So you want to make it "right recursive" so to speak?

Comment: Not sure if grammar term is applicable here, but yes, kind of

Comment: Even the "non recursive" case is not immediate to me. We have 4 cases on the two arguments: left/left, left/right, right/left, right/right. What would you expect the output to be in these 4 cases?

Comment: If I've understood what you're asking, your question boils down to _generically reassociating nested `Either`s_. You want to generalise `exchange :: Either (Either a b) c -> Either a (Either b c)` so that when `a` or `b` are `Either`s they also get right-associated. Is that accurate?

Comment: First `Left` to occur is the result:

`adjoin (Left a) _ = Left a` and `adjoin _ (Left c) = Right $ Right $ Left c`

Let's omit the case when both are `Right` in the non-recursive case for now.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Yes, I think it is.

Comment: It seems like shapeless coproduct is essentially a Scala implementation of [GHC generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Generic).

Comment: ...or [scrap your boilerplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb); that's what it actually cites in [the readme](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/README.md). Anyways, you're trying to reproduce something from Scala that Scala has reproduced from Haskell...

Comment: @leftaroundabout the problem is that I do know how to operate with it in shapeless, like implementing mentioned `Adjoin`, but not in Haskell

Comment: So why don't you show exactly what you want to accomplish, and how you do it in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote another answer but it was incorrect because it didn't recursively flatten  nested `Either`s. Hopefully this one should work.

Some required extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, 
             UndecidableInstances, FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}    -- To enable supplying types with @ 
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-} -- Not strictly necessary, just to avoid Proxy
```

And the class itself:

```
class Flatten input result | input -> result where
    flatten :: input -> result

-- Branch can be used as a kind thanks to DataKinds
data Branch = RebalanceNeeded
            | RebalanceNotNeeded
            | Atomic

type family WhichBranch t :: Branch where
     WhichBranch (Either (Either _ _) _) = RebalanceNeeded
     WhichBranch (Either _ _)            = RebalanceNotNeeded
     WhichBranch _                       = Atomic

class Flatten' (branch :: Branch) input result | branch input -> result where
    flatten' :: input -> result

-- We always delegate on the auxiliary class 
instance Flatten' (WhichBranch input) input result => Flatten input result where
    flatten = flatten' @(WhichBranch input)

-- The left branch is itself another either. We need to rebalance and keep flattening.
instance Flatten (Either x (Either y z)) r 
  => Flatten' RebalanceNeeded (Either (Either x y) z) r where
  flatten' e = case e of
      Left (Left x)  -> flatten @(Either x (Either y z)) (Left x)
      Left (Right y) -> flatten @(Either x (Either y z)) (Right (Left  y))
      Right z        -> flatten @(Either x (Either y z)) (Right (Right z))

-- The left branch is not itself an either. We only flatten the right branch.
instance (Flatten y y') => Flatten' RebalanceNotNeeded (Either x y) (Either x y') where
  flatten' e = case e of
      Left x  -> Left x
      Right y -> Right (flatten @y y)

instance Flatten' Atomic x x where
  flatten' = id
```

The solution makes use of a `WhichBranch` type family to scrutinize the leftmost type. The result is fed into an auxiliary typeclass `Flatten'` that works with the extra information. This is a workaround to avoid annoying "overlapping instances" errors.

Another option would be to simply to put `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}` and `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` pragmas on the instances and work without the auxiliary class and without the type family.

Example of use:

```
ghci> :t flatten (undefined :: Either (Either Bool Float) (Either (Either Char Word) Int))
Either Bool (Either Float (Either Char (Either Word Int)))
```

**Edit:** Instead of multi-parameter typeclasess, another way of encoding these *unidirectional* transformations is with [associated type families](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?#associated-data-and-type-families):

```
class Flatten input where
  type Flattened input -- associated type family that "computes" the flattened type
  flatten :: input -> Flattened input

class Flatten' (branch :: Branch) input where
  type Flattened' branch input 
  flatten' :: input -> Flattened' branch input

instance Flatten' (WhichBranch input) input => Flatten input where
    type Flattened input = Flattened' (WhichBranch input) input
    flatten = flatten' @(WhichBranch input)

instance Flatten                  (Either x (Either y z)) 
  => Flatten' RebalanceNeeded     (Either (Either x y) z) where
  type Flattened' RebalanceNeeded (Either (Either x y) z) 
     = Flattened                  (Either x (Either y z))
  flatten' e = flatten (case e of
      Left (Left x)  -> Left x
      Left (Right y) -> Right (Left  y)
      Right z        -> Right (Right z) 
                                :: Either x (Either y z))

instance Flatten y => Flatten' RebalanceNotNeeded (Either x y) where
  type Flattened' RebalanceNotNeeded (Either x y) = Either x (Flattened y)
  flatten' = fmap flatten

instance Flatten' Atomic x where
  type Flattened' Atomic x = x
  flatten' = id
```

With the advantage that now we can explicitly *ask* to compute the result type:

```
ghci> :kind! (Flattened (Either (Either Bool Float) (Either (Either Char Word) Int)))
Either Bool (Either Float (Either Char (Either Word Int)))
```

Comment: Related: "Avoid overlapping instances with closed type families" https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-02-05-avoid-overlapping-instances-with-closed-type-families.html

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome!
Also, what is the meaning of `@` near a type?

Comment: @SergeyKolbasov It's a type application https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications It's not strictly needed, the alternative is resolving type ambiguities by adding `Data.Proxy` arguments with normal type annotations.